# ¡¡Error en mi código!

Tags: javascript

¡Buen día! estoy practicando con una app de tareas que conseguí por internet, la consola me dice que tengo un error, mas no lo encuentro incluso viendo el vídeo varias veces, ¿alguien puede decirme donde esta el error?
¡¡Muchas gracias!!

```
(function(){

     

    var lista = document.getElementById("lista"),
        btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btn-agregar"),
        tareaInput = document.getElementById("tareaInput");

    

  var agregarTarea = function(){};


  var compInput = function(){};


var eliminarTarea = function(){};

    


    btnAgregar.addEventListener("click",agregarTarea);


        

    tareaInput.addEventListener("click",compInput);

        
        
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= lista.children.length -1 ; i++ ){

lista.children[i].addEventListener("click",eliminarTarea);

    };




}());
```

Comment: me sobran parentesis ahi... y sin saber cual es la idea del codigo, y el error, dificil saber que problema tenes...

Comment: Según la consola  el error está ubicado en el btn.addEventListener()

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: main.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:24
    at main.js:42

Comment: todo eso le falta a la pregunta.. no hay magos aca.. hay que ser bien claros.. y eso quiere decir que btn no es nada.. en algun momento le diste valor?

Comment: la linea 24 es la que comienza con btn-agregar 
y la 42 es la ultima linea

Comment: A btnAgregar le dí el valor de un botón que esta en mi hoja html

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar el error que recibes y la mayor cantidad de código que sea util para que podamos ayudarte. Te invito a leer este articulo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para aprender a redactar una buena pregunta. El título de tu pregunta no ayuda